# How handle Firebase error "Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds"

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It isn't a real problem but I've been wondering for months. How can Handle the Firebase Error "Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds."

So, I read that the problem is coused by my adblocker, so, it cut the unexpected conecction if i don't focus the chrome tab. So, that's the reason that I don't worry by the app

The enviroment for this issue is in Angular Apps with firebase conection by @angular/fire library.

Then, I tryed to use catch errors in every query and don't works. And the console message don't show a path or file where I can catch error.

So, if you know how can i handle this error I'll be very gratfull

Pd. Maybe you seen the error, if not, this is the screenshot

[image: Firebase Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is just letting you know what happened - the app is offline for some reason and can't reach Firestore.  This currently not a situation you can handle in code, as the SDK is designed to work while offline.  While offline, queries will be handled using the [local persistence layer](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline).  It will automatically switch back over to the server when a connection can be made again.

Since it's not an error to be offline, that only thing you can really do is check the [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline#listen_to_offline_data) of your snapshots to see if the snapshot came from the cache.  That will at least let you know that you might not have the most recent data.

Comment: Ok, helpful answer and understand. But some times, don't switch back, is the reason why I wanna take actions

Comment: If you have a bug report for the SDK you're using, I suggest filing that with whoever created it, along with your debugging information.

Comment: Can I catch this error?

Comment: @AyushKumar Read the answer again.  "This currently is not a situation you can handle in code".